# Ext Window is not getting close

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, extjs3

I have one window and having two items on that. In second item which is `panel`, In Item of panel am pushing some data in `afterrender`. After that all othe operation is happening fine but window close is not happening.

```
 afterrender: function(){
    var p = this;
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('GRID');
    var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
    var actionRecItemsLen = record.length;
    var recItem = p.items.items;
    for(var i=0;i<actionRecItemsLen; i++){
            var clsName = new Recordrfc();  // Getting a container class.
            recItem.push(clsName); 
        }
            this.doLayout();
}
```

Here when i am using `recItem.push(clsName);` then `close` icon and cancel button is not working. After sometime page become unresponsive. What possible mistake I am doing.

Comment: what is your Recordrfc() ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use add method of container (Window is container) to add new components. The items property is just collection for storing added compoentns. For adding new component to container needs much more actions than just add object to collection items, and all this actions placed inside add method. Try this:

```
 afterrender: function(){        
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('GRID');
        var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
        var actionRecItemsLen = record.length;        
        for(var i=0; i < actionRecItemsLen; i++){
            var clsName = new Recordrfc();  // Getting a container class.
            this.add(clsName); 
        }

        this.doLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Yes but in this case it adding only one `clsName `. In that way existence of for loop is not matter.

Comment: Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: You create new item on each loop iteration. I think my code should work exactly as your, but I use method add() to add new component. So, it should create one new Recordrfc instance on each selection in grid, and add it in component. I think that problems with Recordrfc, maybe it can not be created more than once? Let's try add it twice manualy:

`afterrender: function(){
        var clsName1 = new Recordrfc();
        this.add(clsName1); 
        var clsName2 = new Recordrfc(); 
        this.add(clsName2); 
        this.doLayout();
}`